# Поделиться ссылкой на вопрос

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

В подвале вопроса есть предложение поделиться ссылкой на вопрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю, что правильным будет заменить "Поделиться" на "Поделитесь", так как по сути это продолжение предыдущего вопросительного предложения: знаете - поделитесь.