# Нужна запятая в предложении ознакомиться с другими вопросами

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В подвале [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3700/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81?__=746144664) во фразе:

> Ознакомьтесь с другими вопросами отмеченными ...

нужна запятая перед "отмеченными".

Скриншот:

[image: зпт]

Возможно еще есть смысл добавить слово "метками" перед самими метками.

При этом еще точка в конце смотрится несколько необычно после тегов.

Comment: Поправил, за исключением добавления слова «метками».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на главном сайте (не Мета) слово "метки" присутствует. Причем в данном случае отсутствует множественная форма "метками". [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566334/Скрипт-некорректно-работает-в-браузере-internet-explorer-Как-исправить).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky таким образом, мне кажется, текущую проблему надо расширить и решить более комплексно.

Comment: «Отмеченный метками» – как–то не звучит в этом контексте. Подскажите, видите ли вы какие-либо альтернативы?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky можно и на основном убрать "метки". Главное, чтобы было единообразно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, «вопросами, отмеченными как {имена меток}»?

Comment: @Arhad Подскажите, пожалуйста, согласно какому правилу языка или разговорной норме добавляется «как».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, согласно правилу согласования падежей.

Винительный падеж (с которым и используется предлог «как») совпадает с именительным применительно к неодушевлённым существительным. Благодаря этому свойству именительный падеж меток прекрасно согласуется с левой частью фразы.

Без предлога же главная часть фразы находится в винительном падеже — имеет место несогласованность.